# Can't change default python version via alias

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I installed python 3.8.5 with instructions from the docs.
Now my default python version is still 3.7.7

```
[agolys@linux ~]$ python --version
Python 3.7.7
```

But my python3 version is 3.8.5

```
[agolys@linux ~]$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

I tried to change it using alias, but it doesn't work:

```
[agolys@linux ~]$ alias python='/usr/bin/python3'
[agolys@linux ~]$ python --version
Python 3.7.7
```

Also PyCharm 'doesn't see' the 3.8 version, I can't make venv using it.

When I tried to make venv using python3 PyCharm is still showing "python 3.7"

Do you have any solution? I just need python 3.8 venv

EDIT: I use Fedora 31

Comment: Aliases are used by interactive shells. PyCharm doesn't use the shell to run scripts, it runs it directly. There's probably a place in the PyCharm preferences where you can specify the full path to the Python interpreter.

Comment: But how can I change the default python interpreter?

Comment: Also there is no python3.8 in usr/bin, but the python3 is told to be 3.8, and PyCharm doesn't agree, so what's the true version of python3?

Comment: do: sudo dnf install python38

Comment: Then python3.8 to launch python 3.8